# Intersect but have both objects at hand afterwards?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two lists of objects (ID, Name, Flag). I have an equality comparer for those objects which compares the ID only.

I want to build the intersection of both lists, and from this intersection I want to have all objects where obj1.Flag != obj2.Flag, however:

```
var result = list1.Intersect(list2, new MyEqualityComparer());
```

Returns only objects from list1, so I can't put that `.Where(x => x.Object1.Flag != x.Object2.Flag)` into the query.

How to do that with LINQ?

Example data:

```
List1:
(1, X, true), (2, Y, true), (3, Z, false)

List2:
(1, X, true), (2, Y, false)

Result:
(2, Y, false)
```

Comment: In your desired result, why do you want the one from `List2` rather than the one from `List1` ?

Comment: Good question, I don't really care. I just need to know the flag somehow. If it is the other one, I need to `!flag` and it's okay as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netcore-3.1):

```
new[] { (1, "X", true), (2, "Y", true), (3, "Z", false) }
    .Join(new[] {(1, "X", true), (2, "Y", false)}, l => l.Item1, r => r.Item1, (l,r) => (l,r))
    .Where(t => t.l.Item3 != t.r.Item3)
    .Select(t => t.l)
```

Or possibly more adapted to your case:

```
var result = list1
    .Join(list2, l => l.Id, r => r.Id, (l,r) => (l,r))
    .Where(t => t.l.Flag != t.r.Flag)
    .Select(t => t.l)
```

Or you can try adding the `obj1.Flag != obj2.Flag` condition to your comparer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **extension methods** in c#.

*Main.cs*:

```cs
var list_1 = new List < Item > () {
  new Item(1, "X", true),
  new Item(2, "Y", true),
  new Item(3, "Z", false)
};
var list_2 = new List < Item > () {
  new Item(1, "X", true),
  new Item(2, "Y", false)
};

var list_3 = list_1.ItemsIntersect(list_2);
```

*ListExtensions.cs*:

```cs
public static class ListExtensions {
  public static IEnumerable < T > ItemsIntersect < T > (this List < T > list_1, List < T > list_2) where T: IItem {
    var result = list_1.Join(list_2, l =>l.Id, r =>r.Id, (l, r) =>(l, r)).Where(t =>t.l.Flag != t.r.Flag).Select(t =>t.l);

    return result;
  }
}
```

*IItem.cs*

```cs
public interface IItem {
  int Id {
    get;
  }
  string Name {
    get;
  }
  bool Flag {
    get;
  }
}
```

*Item.cs*

```cs
public class Item: IItem {
  public int Id {
    get;
    private set;
  }
  public string Name {
    get;
    private set;
  }
  public bool Flag {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  public Item(int id, string name, bool flag) {
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
    Flag = flag;
  }
}
```